# Set the HTDS options for a ruleset deployed on the Business Rules service on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, business-rules

When using the Rule Execution Server console (for the Business Rules service on Bluemix), I can edit the following HTDS Options for a ruleset:

- Hosted transparent decision service location
- Web service endpoint
- Decision service target namespace (SOAP only)
- Decision service parameter target namespace

Can I configure these options for the ruleset before deploying it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could configure these options in the Rule Designer, before deploying the ruleset to the Business Rules service. I set the following ruleset properties in the RuleApp definition:

- ilog.console.htds.context
- ilog.console.wsdl.endpoint
- wsdl.targetnamespace
- wsdl.paramtargetnamespace